# do google data-studio community visualizations have access to my data?

Tags: looker-studio

I want to use some community visualizations, but not clear on the data policy.
I was thinking there might be some type of permissions model, but since they are self-hosted, not sure if the code is reviewed? Maybe similar to chrome plugins?

It seems these can't really be trusted with valuable data, but I can only find very limited docs. appreciate any pointers

eg
https://developers.google.com/datastudio/visualization/issues?hl=en

> Requests for external resources are restricted via a Content Security Policy (CSP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is information current as of 2021-08.

1. Broadly speaking, all community visualizations fall into three groups:

   - [Published Google Visualizations](https://datastudio.google.com/visualization): These are developed and maintained by Google. These are directly covered by Data Studio's [Terms of Service](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7019158) and [Privacy Policy](https://policies.google.com/privacy).
   - [Published Partner Visualizations](https://datastudio.google.com/visualization): These are developed by Data Studio partners. These go through a [review process](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/visualization/publish) before getting published in the gallery. It is mandatory for all partners to link to their Terms of Service as well as Privacy Policy from within their viz.
   - [All unpublished visualizations](https://datastudio.google.com/visualization): Anything else outside of the above two groups. Can be developed and shared by anyone. These may or may not have any Terms of Service and/or Privacy Policy.
2. Even though partner and unpublished visualizations are self-hosted, they run in browser sandbox (as [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68690179/4024072) by @user16586978). These visualizations cannot talk to any external endpoints as [external resources are restricted](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/visualization/issues#limitations) via a [Content Security Policy (CSP)](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp). To render any visualization, the viz code *has to* have access to your data. However, CSP is put in place to prevent exposing that data to any external endpoint.
3. Given this, you should review Terms of Service as well as the Privacy Policy of whatever Community viz you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Data Studio loads the Javascript of the community visualization and runs it locally in the user browser sandbox. The name of the fields and the data is transfered to this script. A potential harmful script may upload these data to an attacker domain. However, I guess that some restrictions are in the sandbox to prevent that.

I would recommend to reviewing a community visualization by yourself and hosting it on your own, if critcal data is going trough that. At least that is our company rule, due to that no community visualization are (officially) used.